# Linear regression and standardization

Tags: statistics, regression

I am trying to use a linear regression to model an expected value Y for an input X.

X and Y have a large difference between them, so I was converting to standard (z) score, doing my calculation (finding where Y would be when X is at a certain level) and converting back to the raw score for Y.

However I am getting numbers that make me think I'm doing something wrong.

Is this a valid way to predict what a "raw score" would be, or should I be doing this another way? It's been many years since I've taken statistics.

Comment: If you could be specific about what makes you think something is wrong, then maybe someone here could help with that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Also, it shouldn't matter whether there is a difference between $X$ and $Y$. If $X$ is measured in gallons and $Y$ in dollars, then there's no such thing as a difference between them. And linear regression treats them just as if they're on different scales like that. If you post your data here, or at least something explaining why you decided to standardize them, then maybe I could understand what you're actually saying. At any rate, if you do an affine transformation of $Y$, then that same affine transformation should apply to the fitted values and residuals. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you standardize both your $X$ and your $Y$, then you are predicting the values of standardized $Y$, in which case you can convert it back to its original scale after prediction.  You can also only standardize your predictor $X$ while leaving your $Y$ unstandardized (this is more common) in order to predict $Y$ based on the way $X$ deviates from its mean.

Standardization usually involves centering and/or scaling.  Centering transforms your variables so that their mean is $0$ whereas scaling transforms your variables so that their standard deviation is $1$.

If your values don't make sense, make sure that no mistakes are being made during standardization.  You should also check to make sure that your data satisfies the assumptions necessary for linear regression to provide a good fit.  Issues like non-normality of your residuals and heteroscedasticity of the data will mean that your model will produce erroneous results.

Comment: The weirdness is that the predicted values were lower than expected, even though my correlation coefficient was fairly high. I think perhaps the regression is predictive only relative to a smaller mean based on a subset of recent data (that is, Y stays relatively static but occasionally has very large fluctuations, at which point it gets relatively static again - I believe that X predicts these variations between the large fluctuations).

Comment: It's difficult to say much without actually seeing your data, but keep in mind that a high correlation does not necessarily imply anything about how "low" or "high" you should expect your predicted values to be.  A high correlation between $X$ and $Y$ simple implies that $Y$ tends to vary in the same direction as the predictor $X$.